# Typesetting <= and < symbols using the default document font

Tags: fonts, symbols

I am writing a document where I need to describe the behaviour of a given system when a parameter is in a given range (e.g. 1 <= x < 100). The document does not otherwise contain equations or any math stuff. I am using the Source Sans Pro font from Adobe and I am having trouble with the <= and < symbols.

- If I use `$\leq$` for the <= symbol, it looks different than the rest of the text, but more specifically, quite different than the < symbol
- If I use `$\leq$` and `$<$`, then they look 'similar' but the baselines don't seem to be aligned (and anyway they look different from the rest of the text)

Here's an image showing both options:

[image]

Is there a way to typeset the <= symbol using the same font as the rest of the document? Failing that, is there a way to have the baselines of the <= and < symbols aligned?

Update: I am using pdflatex. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\begin{document}

1 $\leq$ abs(x) < 100

1 $\leq$ abs(x) $<$ 100

\end{document}
```

Comment: Show a complete example so that we don't have to guess your engine and the font you use.

Comment: in traditional mathematical composition, signs of operation and relation are aligned on a "math axis", which runs along their centerline.  "baseline" alignment is not traditional.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right, I did not specify the engine. As for the font, it is clearly stated in the question: Source Sans Pro from Adobe.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know, but that does not solve my problem. This doc hardly contains any math and the standard "math axis" alignment looks weird here.

Comment: If you want to avoid maths, why don't you just write it in words:  `when the absolute value of $x$ is 1 or more, but less than 100.`

Comment: I don't want to "avoid maths". I want to write an inequality in the way I described, but with the baselines of the < and <= symbols aligned.

Comment: There are two version of the font on CTAN: the otf and the .pfb. With lualatex/xelatex which would use the otf it would be easy. You could simply access the U+2264 glyph. With pdflatex and the .pfb it is not so easy. As far as I can see the package hasn't encoded it. So you would have to create tfm, enc and fd-files if you want to use it.

Comment: If you're wanting to use symbolic form, the entire inequality should be within math mode, not just the relational operators. That won't help with your font-consistency issue though

Comment: @Fox I simply want to either use the same Source Sans Pro font, or otherwise align the baselines.

Comment: Consider `\textlessequal` from `inputenx` (not tested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes the baseline as I needed:

```
1 $\leq$ abs(x) \raisebox{1pt}{$<$} 100
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Did you try `\textless` instead of `$<$`?

Comment: Yes, but `\textless` gives the same result than just `<`

Answer (score 6):

With lualatex/xelatex using the glyph from SourceSansPro is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SourceSansPro}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textlessthanequal}       \UnicodeEncodingName{"2264}
\begin{document}
1 ^^^^2264 x < 2

1 ≤  x < 2 

1 \textlessthanequal{} x < 2
\end{document}
```

[image]

With pdflatex it is more difficult. This here is a **hack** to avoid to have to do much work. It assumes that less equal as the same width as less.

1. Find `SourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base.tfm` (in fonts/tfm)
2. Copy it e.g. to your current folder.
3. Rename the copy to `XSourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base.tfm`
4. Find `a_ggs4wk.enc` (in fonts/enc)
5. Copy it.
6. Rename the copy to `Xa_ggs4wk.enc`
7. Open `Xa_ggs4wk.enc`
8. Change the line `/AutoEnc_ggs4wkuzes44fkerkgtyzffacb [` to `/XAutoEnc_ggs4wkuzes44fkerkgtyzffacb [`
9. Find in the file `/less` and change it to `/lessequal`
10. Save the file.
11. Test if it works with this document:

    ```
     \documentclass{book}

    \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

    \pdfmapline{=XSourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base XSourceSansPro-Regular "XAutoEnc_ggs4wkuzes44fkerkgtyzffacb ReEncodeFont" <[Xa_ggs4wk.enc <SourceSansPro-Regular.pfb}

    \makeatletter
    \DeclareFontEncoding{U}{}{}
    \DeclareFontFamily{U}{xsourcesans}{}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{xsourcesans}{m}{n}
     { <->  XSourceSansPro-Regular-lf-t1--base
      }{}
    \newcommand\textlessequal{{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{xsourcesans}\selectfont <}}
    \begin{document}

    1 \textlessequal{} abs(x) < 100

    \end{document}
    ```

[image]

In both cases the less sign is not aligned along the baseline of the less equal sign. You can do it with your raisebox command, but imho it will look odd.

Comment: I guess luatex / xelatex are worth having a look. I will need to try and see how difficult it is to migrate from pdflatex to one of these..

Comment: `\textlessequal` and `\textgreaterequal` should have found their place in TS1.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could load `MnSymbol` option with `mathspec`. It does not give you the same symbol, but it looks better.

### Result

[image: Result]

### MWE

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\defaultfontfeatures
{ Ligatures      = TeX ,
    Numbers        = Proportional ,
    Extension      = .otf ,
    UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
    ItalicFont     = *-RegularIt ,
    BoldFont       = *-Bold , 
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldIt }
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin){SourceSansPro}

\begin{document}

    1 $\leq$ abs(x) < 100

    1 $\leq$ abs(x) $<$ 100

    $x=12$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The question specifically says I am using pdflatex